# object output in form input

Tags: javascript, jquery

такая проблема:
Есть некий объект(собранный из данных со страницы)
Есть форма с инпутами, при клике они должны заполнятся(данными из объекта) но этого не происходит(событие на кнопку я не вешал интересует сам процесс записи в поля формы данных из  объекта)

и еще проясните как работает `$(element).val(function(index,[тут должна быть ф-ия но она не работает... или я не так передаю...]));`

код прилагаю

```js
//Алгоритм работы:
//1) Жмем кнопочку add и поля сформированного объекта копируются в поля формы(input)
//2)далее жмем еще раз add и поля объекта копируются/заполняются еще раз в поля формы() и так по кругу пока не заполним все значения из данных объекта сформированных из .showcase;
var $showcase = $('.showcase'),
  $form = $('.formOrder');
var $goods = $showcase.find('.item-goods');
var $name, $articul, $descr, $quantity;
$arr = [];
$goods.each(function(index, el) {
  $name = $(el).find('.name').text();
  $articul = $(el).find('.articul').text();
  $descr = $(el).find('.descr').text();
  $quantity = $(el).find('.quantity').html()[0];
  if ($goods.length > 0) {
    $arr.push({
      name: $name,
      descr: $descr,
      articul: $articul,
      quantity: $quantity
    });
  }
});
//объект вывелся в консоли, как сделать чтобы вывод  первых двух полей
//объекта выводился в input (планируется нажимать на кнопку add в .showcase)
//и происходит заполнение input
for (var key in $arr) {
  console.log($arr[key]);
}
//пробывал так
$form.find('input').each(function(index, el) {
  //  $(el).val($arr[index].name);
  //выводит или то или это а мне надо чтобы они выводились вместе
  //кроме того если полей формы больше чем в полях объекта выводится ошибка
  // свойство не может быть записано в поле вданном случае name не найдено
  //  $(el).val($arr[index].articul);
});
//пробывал и так
for ($i = 0; $i < $arr.length; $i++) {
  // $form.find('input').val($arr[$i].name);
  //таже чушь
  // $form.find('input').val($arr[$i].articul);
}
$form.find('input[name=goods_articul]').val($arr[0].name);
$form.find('input[name=goods_quantity]').val($arr[0].articul);
$form.find('input[name=goods_articul]').val($arr[1].name);
$form.find('input[name=goods_quantity]').val($arr[1].articul);
//не работает
// for(i=0;i<$arr.length;i++){
//   $form.find('input[name=goods_articul]').val($arr[i].name);
// $form.find('input[name=goods_quantity]').val($arr[i].articul);
// $form.find('input[name=goods_articul]').val($arr[i].name);
// $form.find('input[name=goods_quantity]').val($arr[i].articul);
// }
//Этот вариант вообще не сработал читал документацию ни черта не понял... во всяком случае чтобы работало:
// $('.formOrder').find('input').each(function(index,el){
//  $(el).val(function(index,findObj));
// })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="formOrder out">

  <div class="wrap static st">
    <br />
    <!-- <input type="text" name="goods_name" placeholder="Название..." class="static" value=""> -->
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="goods_articul" placeholder="Код..." class="static" value="">
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="goods_quantity" placeholder="Количество товара..." class="static" value="">

    <br />
    <input type="text" name="goods_articul" placeholder="Код..." class="static" value="">
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="goods_quantity" placeholder="Количество товара..." class="static" value="">

    <button class="delContent btn hidd" type="button">Удалить блок</button>
  </div>
  <div class="showcase">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="item-goods">
          <div class="name">good1</div>
          <div class="descr">nice good</div>
          <div class="articul">#34355</div>
          <div class="quantity">1 <span>шт</span></div>
          <div class="group-b">
            <button class="addFields btn">Add / <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
            <!-- <button>Like / <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button> -->
            <button>Del / <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="item-goods">
          <div class="name">good2</div>
          <div class="descr">very nice</div>
          <div class="articul">#34356</div>
          <div class="quantity">1 <span>шт</span></div>
          <div class="group-b">
            <button class="addFields btn">Add / <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
            <!-- <button>Like / <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button> -->
            <button>Del / <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="item-goods">
          <div class="name">good3</div>
          <div class="descr">so good</div>
          <div class="articul">#34357</div>
          <div class="quantity">1 <span>шт</span></div>
          <div class="group-b">
            <button class="addFields btn">Add / <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
            <!-- <button>Like / <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button> -->
            <button>Del / <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
```

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/TOvWV0IOoc7SXG4L?preview

Comment: Попробуйте заполнять вот так `$form.find('input[name=goods_articul]').val($arr[0].name);
 $form.find('input[name=goods_quantity]').val($arr[0].articul);`

Comment: класс, направление верное, но не могу понять как это сделать в цикле ставлю цикл for(i=0;i<$arr.length;i++);
$form.find('input[name=goods_articul]').val($arr[i].name); $form.find('input[name=goods_quantity]').val($arr[i].articul);
и выводится повтором последний 3 объект как бы вывести не повторяясь , и при этом не добавляя новые названия классов для input

Comment: Попробуйте заполнять так  `var goods_articuls = $form.find('input[name=goods_articul]');
var goods_quantities = $form.find('input[name=goods_quantity]');
$arr.forEach(function (item, index) {
    goods_articuls.eq(index).val(item.name);
    goods_quantities.eq(index).val(item.articul);
});`

Comment: Шикарно,низкий поклон оказалось дело было в forEach. и eq, for и for in значит для этого не подойдет или я что то не так делаю, в любом случае спасибо =)

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Некий объект
var values = {
 input1: "text 1",
 input2: "text 2",
};

$("[name=input1]").val(values.input1); // Заполнили инпут по простому

// Заполнили инпут перебирая объект
for (var input in values) {
 $("[name=" + input + "]").val(values[input]);
}

// судя по документации val с функцией используется скорее
// всего для того чтобы не срабатывало событие change
// для заполнения удобнее пользоваться другими методами
$("form input").val(function (index, oldValue) {
 return $.trim(oldValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- форма с инпутами -->
<form>
  <input name="input1"/>
  <input name="input2"/>
</form>
```

Comment: тоже не плохой вариант только менее универсальный, чем предложил Vladimir. последняя строка не понятна  в аргументе oldValue(это же ф-ия? тогда где она описана, исходя из этого не очень понятно что же должно было вернуть).